# How to specify a local file within html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an HTML project, and I could not find out how to open the link on local file html without using `javascript`. As i wish to open `FastDeposit.html` on my local file directory.

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="kjzf fourpage" url="/FastDeposit.html" style="display: block;">
            <ul>
                <li><a>工行秒到</a><i></i></li>
                <p>方便，秒到，单笔存款最低100元，上限100万元，仅支持工商银行。</p>
            </ul>
            <div class="icbciconwh"></div>
        </div>
```

My Local file Directory Image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to link to is in the same folder, you can just use `filename.html`, without using a slash before it. If you use a slash (like `/image.jpg`), it will look for the file in the root of your web-files directory.

To reference a local file, you can use `file://` as the protocol (to replace `http://`).

An example of a local file URL could be `file://localhost/etc/fstab` for UNIX systems or `file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi` for Windows systems.

As the poster above me also mentioned, a link needs to be incapsulated in an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).